# Every finite Borel Measure on a complete separable Metric Space is tight

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to understand the proof of the Theorem in the title which I found here
https://www.math.leidenuniv.nl/~vangaans/jancol1.pdf. (Theorem 2.6)
The proof is very good in my opinion however I don't understand why he can choose
$\bigcup _{  }^{ \infty  }{ B({ a }_{ n, }\delta )=X } $ in the 4th line.
If I'm not fully mistaken, it doesn't hold in general that every complete metric space can be represented as a union of open balls.
Could someone explain to me why he is allowed to make such a choice?

Comment: Just as a comment, the title of your question is misleading. Your problem is entirely about topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a metric space, the open balls are well defined. In particular, they exist and $B(a_{n},\delta)\subset X$ holds. This implies that $\bigcup_{i}B(a_{i},\delta)\subset X.$

Now take $x\in X$. Since the sequence of points $\{a_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is dense in X, $\exists i\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $d(a_{i},x)<\frac{\delta}{2}$. In particular, $x\in B(a_{i},\delta)$. Since $x\in X$ was arbitrary, we conclude that $X\subset \bigcup_{i} B(a_{i},\delta)$.

Comment: Thanks I get it! actually pretty easy